# symfony doctrine move an entity object to another entity type

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there any way to move a row to another mysql table with Doctrine?

I am searching for the equivalent of the following mysql:

```
INSERT myTableCopy (
   SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = 2
)
```

I expect something like this:

```
// $first is an object from  myTable
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:MyTable')->findOneBy(array('id' => 2));
$second = new myTableCopy();
$second = clone $first;
```

Unfortunately (but logically), the $second entity is of type myTable...

How can I do this?

*I know I can use prepare statement, but I want to know if I can do this with one of the Doctrine function.*

*FYI: I have a huge table (several millions of rows), and I want to move old data to a "backup table" that would not be so used*

PS: I know that [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8459120/5165343) is proposing the following solution, but I think that there should be a better way with serializer/normalizer...

```
 // now loop over the properties of each post array...
    foreach ($post as $property => $value) {
        // create a setter
        $method = sprintf('set%s', ucwords($property)); // or you can cheat and omit ucwords() because PHP method calls are case insensitive
        // use the method as a variable variable to set your value
        $post->$method($value);
    }
```

Comment: change this `>getRepository('MyBundle:myTableCopy')`. this should be entity name

Comment: @Abdulla, as describe in the question, I want to copy/move one row from MyTable to MyTableCopy. How would I be able to select the object I want to copy from MyTableCopy??

Comment: Just fill your data with setters or constructor.

Comment: @chapay, a bit more details?...

Comment: The method you described in the PS section. But I don't think you should do it using ORM, if you have several million rows, better use DBAL(it's an abstraction layer over PDO).

Comment: @chapay, actually, I used pureSql to move the "already old" rows. Now, when I access a data, if I mark it as old, I want to move it to the other table. So can you give me detailed instruction about how you would do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the error after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216285/symfony-2-clone-entity-to-different-table) from @Colin M.

Here is the final solution of my problem:

```
$myOriginalObject = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:MyTable')->findOneBy(array('id' => 2));
// Here modify the original object if needed...

$myTableCopyObject = new myTableCopy();

$oldReflection = new \ReflectionObject($myOriginalObject);
$newReflection = new \ReflectionObject($myTableCopyObject);

foreach ($oldReflection->getProperties() as $property) {
    if ($newReflection->hasProperty($property->getName())) {
        $newProperty = $newReflection->getProperty($property->getName());
        $newProperty->setAccessible(true);
        $property->setAccessible(true);
        $newProperty->setValue($myTableCopyObject, $property->getValue($doi_tmp));
    }
}               

$this->em->persist($myTableCopyObject);
$this->em->remove($myOriginalObject);
$this->em->flush();
```

**NB: only the ID seem to not be conserved when you have an auto-increment ID**

Answer (score 1):

### This is possible via reflection

**Situation when your $oldEntity already has (for example) a date object (thus normalize won't work and will throw an error)**

*In this situation, symfony's method didn't work because my $oldEntity already had a date object and kept getting errors*

*This assumes that you have getters/setters for both entities AND that the $oldEntity public method getter/setters exist in the $newEntityh, but can easily be adapted to whatever situation*

```
$reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($oldEntity);
//get all the methods that start with get
$methods = array_filter($reflectionClass->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC), function(ReflectionMethod $method){
     return strpos($method->name, "get") === 0;
});

foreach ($methods as $method) {
   $methodName = $method->name;
   //replace the 'get' string of method with 'set'
   $setter = str_replace("get", "set", $methodName);
   $value = $oldEntity->$methodName();
   $newEntity->$setter($value);
}

//new entity is populated
```

### This is possible via a [normalizer](https://api.symfony.com/4.1/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer.html).

**Situation when the new entity already exists:**

```
  /** create newEntity */
  $newEntity = new User();
  /** populate it ? */

  $normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer();

  $normalizer->denormalize(
      $normalizer->normalize($oldEntity),
      //Could use instead of get_class: User::class 
      get_class($newEntity), null, ['object_to_populate' => $newEntity]
  );
  //$newEntity updated;
```

**Situation when the new entity needs to be created:**

```
  $normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer();

  $newEntity = $normalizer->denormalize(
      $normalizer->normalize($oldEntity),
      $newEntityClassName //use User::class for example to get the name
  );
```